Preserve original number of closed/not-closed points to a shapely Polygon
In the following code:
from shapely import Polygon

a = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0)])
b = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0), (0, 0)])

print(f"{a=}")
print(f"{b=}")

The output is:
a=<POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))>
b=<POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))>

The issue is that we have some existing polygons stored in a database in JSON format, and we want to process those polygons using Shapely and transmit them out the API. We want to preserve the original data in the database, even after transforms using Shapely. In the above example we'd like to be able to distinguish that a only has its original 4 points and doesn't have the duplicated first point at the end.
The user may or may not have added the duplicated first/last point in the database and we simply want to preserve whichever they used.
Is there some way to create a Polygon and communicate is_closed or similar that would allow us to recover the original input points from a Polygon after it has been constructed?
Tested with Shapely 2.0.5.

The first geometry is invalid, which the software helpfully corrects. You can't define an arbitrary definition of polygon for the software, only maintain an external attribute.
